# Replicate iOS 7 homescreen animation

Tags: objective-c, animation, ios7, homescreen

I'd like to replicate the iOS 7 homescreen animation. Mostly I'm interested in zooming in the scrollview to a specific point (top left if the icon is there, middle, or top right, etc)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBL8eQmQaVU

I thought I could use CGAffineTransformMakeScale but I couldn't figure out a way to scale it to a specific point. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use Animation blocks? During the animation you could render a UIImage with the contents of the Scrollview via

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scrollView.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[scrollView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You would put this image in the scrollview as a image view (With the image view's content mode set to resize to fit) overlaying the existing contents and make the image view is the same size as the scrollview at all times. Making it look like the whole scroll view is resizing.

Here is the animation block code.

Zoom Out

```
    scrollView.frame = icon.frame


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    scrollview.frame = window.frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Zoom In

```
scrollView.frame = window.frame


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    scrollview.frame = icon.frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/heikomaass/HMLauncherView) source code which replicates most functionality of iOS home screen.

Comment: Just a heads up: Answering questions with just a link is typically frowned upon due to the risk of link rot (I've been downvoted for it in the past). You should paste whatever relevant code the link has in your answer.

Comment: As far as it answers the question i don't thing it's not necessary to paste code.